# Ajax doesn't work in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

ajax does't work in laravel

```
View/message.php 
<html>
<head>
  <title>Ajax Example</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <script type="application/javascript">
     function getMessage(){
        $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           url:'/getmsg',
           data:'_token = {{ csrf_token() }}',         dataType: 'json',
           success:function(data){
              $("#msg").html(data.msg);
           }
        });
     }
  </script>
```

```
  <div id = 'msg'>This message will be replaced using Ajax. 
     Click the button to replace the message.</div>     

  <?php
     echo Form::button('Replace Message',['onClick'=>'getMessage()']);
  ?>
```

in above code i just click in button (Replace Message) and call ajax

```
Routes.php

Route::get('/ajax',function(){
return view('message');
});
Route::post('/getmsg','AjaxController@index');

AjaxController.php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use ajax;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AjaxController extends Controller {
public function index(){
  $msg = "This is a simple message.";
  return response()->json(array('msg'=> $msg), 200);
}
}
```

but it doesn't work
it show error some like this
POST http://localhost:8000/getmsg 500 (Internal Server Error)

[Tutorial link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_ajax.htm)

Comment: Please provide us your error message.

Comment: POST http://localhost:8000/getmsg 500 (Internal Server Error) in console

Comment: The error message, not the errorcode

Comment: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)" in console

Comment: You should take a look at your nginx logs

Comment: Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

1/1
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

Comment: Hmm, perhaps a php artisan cache:clear would do the trick?

Comment: what is nginx logs?  i don't know. actually i am fresher in laravel

Comment: i tried in command promot :'php artisan cache:clear' but all error as like befor

Comment: Take a look at your nginx logs located at /var/log/nginx/<your-domain-name>.error.log

Comment: no, i cann't find path in my laravel project folder. i am now workeing in local host

Comment: Not in your laravel folder .. I clearly said /var/log folder

Comment: Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

IT IS SOLVED BY JUST CHANGING IN CODE ...
data:{'_token' : '{{ csrf_token() }}'}